# Delete files based on MD5 hash

Tags: hash, cmd

Using Windows command line (not powershell), I want to hash all files within the directory and then remove files that match a particular hash set contained within a text file.

I've considered using md5deep, but I'm unsure if the output of matched files can then be redirected into a delete command.

Any help gratefully received, thank you!

To add some detail; the files are in a directory called 'images'

```
md5deep.exe -r -b -x irrelevant_hashes.txt c:\images
```

This gives me a list of the files that I need to keep.  Is it possible to redirect the output from MD5deep to move the 'good' files to another directory?

Comment: It's great you have all these requirements and limitations. What program did you write to meet them.

Comment: Without seeing your code trial and the format of **your** file containing your md5 hashes it is difficult to give any hints.

Comment: In summary, I've used a batch script to copy files from a folder on the desktop of a computer to a USB pen drive.  There are approximately 1200, of which I know that  probably 70% are likely to be irrelevant system images (icons / folder pictures, etc.).  I'd like to compare the contents of the folder with the NRSL list of irrelevant files and delete the useless content, leaving only files of interest.  Not sure if i'm just asking for the impossible!

Answer (score 0):

For a single md5 key in cmd line it is as easy as:
(Here using the 64bit variant).

```
set "KillMD5=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"
for /f "tokens=1*" %A in ('md5deep64.exe *.* 2^>mul') do @if %A==%KillMD5% @Echo del "%B"
```

For testing the del command is only echoed.
In a batch file double the `%` percent signs `%%A/%%B`

Comment: Thank you for this - I'd really like to find a way to hash a number of files and compare them against a list before deleting, but I'm grateful for your post.

Comment: You were'nt very specific and didn't show much effort. See the `-w/-m/-x` options of md5deep.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try and be a bit more specific:  files exist in a directory called 'images'. The command I've used is md5deep.exe -r -b -x irrelevant_hashes.txt C:\Images > notable.txt  This produces a list of the names of the files I need.  Rather than redirect the 'good' hashes to a text file, is there a way to use the output from MD5Deep and copy the files with those names into a new directory?

Comment: Your command `md5deep.exe -r -b -x irrelevant_hashes.txt C:\Images > notable.txt` can't be used for any copy operations as the `-b` bare file name strips directory information from output. Please add some sample lines from `irrelevant_hashes.txt` to your question

Comment: Would it matter about the `-b` stripping directory data if the files were all in a single directory?  I was wondering if each line from `notable.txt` could be individually processed as a move command, to move the good files to a directory.  If easier, the `x` could be replaced with `m` to only output files requiring deletion.  `irrelevant_hashes.txt` contains MD5 hash values, one per line.

Answer (score 0):

This use pure batch file, take use of **CertUtil** from windows, so **no 3rd** software need.

You only need provide the value for 2 variables:

**`set _nOp=irrelevant_hashes.txt`** :: file text with md5 data for files to delete

**`set "_path_gen=c:\images"`** :: path to files that will be delete.

In additional, put the txt file with md5 (in this code case irrelevant_hashes.txt) in the same folder of the files that you want to delete.

For generate a new md5 from files, and usin **`certUtil`** on **command line**:

```bat
   type nul >"%temp%\MD5_to_del.txt" & cd /d "c:\images" & for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ('^<nul dir /o-d /on /b "c:\images\*.*"') do for /f "tokens=* delims= " %M in ('certutil -hashfile "%i" md5 ^| find /v ":"') do echo/%M>>"%temp%\MD5_to_del.txt"
```

For generate a new md5 from files, and using **`certUtil`** on a **file.bat**:

```bat
   type nul >"%temp%\MD5_to_del.txt" & cd /d "c:\images" & for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('^<nul dir /o-d /on /b "c:\images\*.*"') do for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%M in ('certutil -hashfile "%%i" md5 ^| find /v ":"') do echo/%%M>>"%temp%\MD5_to_del.txt"


@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

cls && mode con cols=120 lines=7 & cd /d "%~dp0" 

set "'=^|"
set "_spc=            "

set /a _cnt_left= 1 - 1

set /a _cnt_treated= 1 - 1
set /a _cnt_deleted= 1 - 1
set /a _cnt_keeped_= 1 - 1
     
set _type_hash=md5

set _show=0000000

set "_path_gen=c:\images"

cd /d !_path_gen! || set "_erro=!_path_gen! not exist?"&& goto :_error_:

set _n_deleted=%temp%\md5_not_deleted_.txt
set _y_deleted=%temp%\md5_was_deleted_.txt

(

if exist "!_n_deleted!" del /q /f "!_n_deleted!"
if exist "!_y_deleted!" del /q /f "!_y_deleted!"

) 2>nul >nul

if exist ".\irrelevant_hashes.txt" ( 

     set _nOp=irrelevant_hashes.txt

    ) else ( 
    
     set "_error= File irrelevant_hashes.txt not found"
     goto :_error_:
    
    )
    
set _hash_data=%temp%\hash_db\date_db.txt

if exist "!_hash_data!" ( 

     del /q /f "!_hash_data!" 
     copy /y "!_nOp!" "!_hash_data!" 2>nul >nul || set _error=Copy !_nOp! to !_hash_data!
     
    ) else (
     
     dir /ad "%temp%\hash_db\" 2>nul >nul | findstr /c:".." || mkdir "%temp%\hash_db" 
     copy  /v "!_nOp!" "!_hash_data!" 2>nul >nul || set _error=Copy !_nOp! to !_hash_data!
    
    )

for /f "delims= " %%T in ('forFiles /p "." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') do set "_tab=%%T"

call set "_tab=%_tab:~0,1%"

for /f "tokens=* delims=^ " %%i in ('^<nul dir /o-d /on /b "!_path_gen!\*.*" 2^> nul ^| find "" /v /c ') do set _cnt_file=%%i

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('dir /o-d /on /b "*.*" ^| findstr /i /v "!_nOp! %0" ') do (

     for %%S in (cnt_treated cnt_deleted cnt_keeped_ cnt_left) do set _show_%%S=!_show!!_%%S!

     set _file=%%~nxf
     set "_file_hash=%%~dpnxf"
     
     set /a _cnt_treated=!_cnt_treated! + 1 
     
     call :_get_hash_:
     
     title Total files: !_show_cnt_treated:~-5! ^| Delete: !_show_cnt_deleted:~-5! ^| Keeped: !_show_cnt_keeped_:~-5! ^| File left: !_show_cnt_left:~-5!
     
    )

(

if exist "!_n_deleted!" copy /y "!_n_deleted!" .
if exist "!_y_deleted!" del /y "!_y_deleted!" .

) 2>nul >nul

echo/ Total file treated: !_show_cnt_treated:~-5! 
echo/ Total file deleted: !_show_cnt_deleted:~-5!
echo/ Total file  keeped: !_show_cnt_keeped_:~-5!

goto :_end_of_file_:

:_get_hash_:

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('certutil -hashfile "!_file_hash!" !_type_hash! ^| find /v ":"') do (
       
          set "_hash=%%i"
     call set "_hash=!_hash: =!"
     
     call set _hash=!_hash!
        
     for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%I in ('echo/%_tab%') do call set _file_hash=!_hash:%%I=!
        
     call set _hash=!_hash!
     
     for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%e in ('type "!_hash_data!" ^| findstr /i /l /c:"!_hash!"') do set _hash_db=%%e
     
     if "!_hash_db!" equ ""  set "_hash_db=-  So, no found^!! not "
          
     echo/ & echo/  File hash md5 from: "!_file!" & echo/
     echo/!_spc!Hash !_type_hash!: !_hash!
     echo/ Data hash md5 ^(db^): !_hash_db! equals?

     call :_delete_md5_:
     
     call set /a _cnt_left=!_cnt_file! - 1 - !_cnt_keeped_!
    
    )
    
    timeout /t 10 2>nul >nul 
    
   )
 
   )
 
for %%C in (file_hash hash strn_hash strn_hash hash_nul hash_db) do set _%%C=

exit /b 

:_delete_md5_:

if /i "!_hash_db!" equ "!_hash!" del /q /f "!_path_gen!\!_file!"

if not exist "!_path_gen!\!_file!" (

     echo/!_file! !_strn_hash!>>"!_y_deleted!" 
     echo/!_spc!!_spc:~-10!!_hash! "!_file!" file was deleted^^! 
     
     call set /a _cnt_file=!_cnt_file! - 1
     call set /a _cnt_deleted=!_cnt_deleted! + 1
     
     exit /b
     
     ) else (
     
     echo/!_file! !_strn_hash!>>"!_n_deleted!" 
     echo/!_spc!!_spc:~-10!!_hash! "!_file!" file not was deleted^^!
     
     call set /a _cnt_keeped_=!_cnt_keeped_! + 1
     
     exit /b
     
    )
    
:_error_:

echo/ & echo/ & echo/ !_error! 

goto :_end_of_file_:


:_end_of_file_:
```

[image]