# Delete Files Based on MD5 Hash?

Tags: md5

I have a bunch of files. I calculated their MD5 hashes and put those in a text file and called it database.txt
I would like to delete all instances of those files (not just duplicates) based on their MD5 hashes from the text file.
Can anyone help out with some batch code or software suggestions?

The closest thing I've found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861527/11980858 but it only deletes duplicates.

Comment: @Babydesta ok, do you have any software or batch script suggestions?

Comment: @Babydesta No, I'm on Windows 7.